# libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, heroku, streamlit

i have a problem while running an app in heroku. The following error message appears:
libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

I created a file called Aptfile and wrote libgl1 inside it but it does not work.

You can find the whole code in my git hub repository: https://github.com/Jose-Villamor/Image-style-tranfer

[Error message that appears when I run the app in heroku](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkv22.png)

Comment: Ok so i have manage to solve the problem. In the requirements.txt file i change the library opencv-python to opencv-python-headless. Got the solution in this site: https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/issues/370. Hope this is useful for someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new text file on github name it

> packages.txt

and add this in

```
reeglut3-dev
libgtk2.0-dev
```